# "Error: Allowed memory size of [...] bytes exhausted" occuring during installation of Shopware 6 on MacOS X using MAMP

Tags: php, symfony, memory, terminal, shopware

I can't install Shopware 6, development template, due to the error

> "Error: Allowed memory size of [...] bytes exhausted"

on MacOS X using MAMP Pro and I actually don't know why. Of course first thing I did was checking the php.ini and the value of the memory limit. I've tried values up to 2048M and even -1, I've checked via grep if this is the right php.ini that gets used and yes it is, but still the same error keeps occurring.

I'm using MAMP Pro on macOS Catalina version 10.15.3, 2,9 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5, 16 GB ram.

Checking the workload using mac's task manager doesn't show any significant load on the ressources so I'm really confused.
And I know and heard from others that they had similar problems so help really is appreciated.

Error message screenshot :

[image: error message screenshot]

Comment: seems like you can only allocate 128MB, you can check your memory limit with `phpinfo()` (in the browser) or with `var_dump(ini_get('memory_limit'))` in the command line, while executing. Either your're not using the right php.ini or the install script overwrites your config. You could also try to use `ini_set('memory_limit', "2048M")` to set the memory dynamic within the script.

Comment: @fehrlich php -i | grep memory_limit returns 2048M

Comment: Based on the error message in your screenshot, it looks like your updated memory limit isn't affecting the script you are running. Most likely the script is using an installation of PHP that's not using your .ini file. I'm not familiar with MAMP, but perhaps the application has its own version of PHP. If so, you might need to look for documentation about how to up the memory limit of PHP within MAMP.

Comment: what is the exact command that you run when you get this error?

Comment: Well, actually it seems that it's the right ini file because if I check via using grep, either the used php ini or the value of the memory_limit itself, it returns the right values.

It's an installation script so I have to track down whats happening inside but it seems that it's happening during data base migrations

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all, I found the issue.
There's actually two .ini files that are being used.
I actually edited the bash profile and the right php version was used but I found out that MAMP Pro actually uses multiple ini files. If I did grep the memory_limit inside the terminal I always got the right value back that I had set up so that's why I didn't bother to look further but there is actually a "base" php.ini file. I don't know which magic MAMP Pro uses to manage those files but maybe the installation process of Shopware calls php in ways that MAMP's mapping fails.

Anyways, when I edited the memory_limit inside the "base" php.ini as well, the problem was solved.

Please look at the screenshot as well, so you understand what I'm talking about [php.ini MAMP setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCOGD.png)

Comment: This helped me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your php is not properly configured on CLI.
MAMP only creates an alias which is not always properly resolved. try adding the MAMP bin folder to your export path in your `~/.profile` like this:
`export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.3/bin`

mysql is not needed but comes in handy sometimes. Make sure to replace the php version to your MAMP installation as 7.3.3 is not available in all installations.